# SSIS Flat File Destination Column Headers

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Is there a way to output a flat file from SSIS that has no column headers?

In the Flat File Connection Manager I tried unchecking the Column names in first data row box, but that does not work. When I open up the connection manager it has been re-checked.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: As long as you press "OK" on the connection manager editor, it should retain your setting.
Unless you have an expression on that property?  Or Package Configurations?  Are you using that connection manager for any other destination or source?

Comment: Thanks! You pointed me in the right direction. It was the configuration file. I completely spaced that one.